# Can I remove SpecflowFeatureFiles tags from my csproj file?

Tags: .net, specflow, csproj

In my csproj file I have lots of SpecflowFeatureFiles tags of the form

```
<SpecFlowFeatureFiles Update="Path\To\Feature\featureName.feature">
    <Visible>$(UsingMicrosoftNETSdk)</Visible>
    <CodeBehindFile>%(RelativeDir)%(Filename).feature$(DefaultLanguageSourceExtension)</CodeBehindFile>
</SpecFlowFeatureFiles>
```

However when I create new feature files a corresponding SpecFlowFeatureFiles tag isn't created, and I've tested deleting the SpecFlowFeatureFiles and they don't appear to do anything.

So are they useless and can I delete them?

I'm using Specflow version 3.9.74.

Comment: It might be a remnant from older SpecFlow versions or it might only be needed when targeting older .net framworks. Have a look at the [SpecFlow's own feature tests](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/blob/8e0e7d4cecacc0dd3267f12c34477c30c84a2c37/Tests/TechTalk.SpecFlow.Specs/TechTalk.SpecFlow.Specs.csproj#L30). There only this line is present: `<SpecFlowFeatureFiles Remove="TestFiles/**/*.feature" />`.

Comment: If removing it from your .csproj doesn't hurt anything, just remove them. Don't worry about it.